# Org Latex Fragment Succeeded by a Dash Is Not Showing

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

I'm using the org-mode to write some mathematical notes, so I'm using
latex fragments like `$\frac{a}{b}$` a lot. However, if I succeed the
fragment with a dash, like `$\frac{a}{b}$-fraction`, it will not
render (preview) the fragment.

Questions:
(1) How can I override this behavior and make it show?
(2) Is this the intended behavior or strictly a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\(...\)` instead of `$...$` and it should work just fine.

Comment: does it work fine for you? for me it isn't recognized as math mode, so it gets typeset as regular text, not a formula

Comment: actually works for me

Answer (score 2):

Org-mode recognizes Latex fragments by the `$` symbol at the start and end of the fragment. If you add a trailing `-`, then the fragment doesn't end with a `$` anymore, so Org won't recognize it as a fragment. You can work around this by placing a space between the closing `$` and the `-`:

```
$\frac{a}{b}$ -fraction
```

Comment: But how can one then supress the space during export? Note that this is possible when dealing with emphasis: `/wh/-pronoun`.

Comment: The code for font-locking, responsible for bold and emphasis, is different than the code for identifying code fragments, so they will not necessarily behave the same. Another work around: try `$\frac{a}{b} - \text{fraction}$`. Do you need to have the '-fraction' outside the fragment for some reason?

Comment: Does the following work? `$\frac{a}{b}$ \hspace{-\em}` (or `-\thinspace`)?